# Pine script ignoring limit price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have this is a script:

```
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, limit=buyPrice, comment=enterLongComment)
```

When I replace it by:

```
 strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, comment=enterLongComment)
```

The backtest is exactly the same. Then I replaced it by the below and the backtest is still the same. Why is limit being ignored? I am using it correctly right?

```
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, limit=1000000, comment=enterLongComment)
```

I am interpreting this correctly as that: the strategy should wait until the price goes up until buyPrice and only then buy.

Comment: Can you give us a numbered example ? It depends on the pair you trade and its price.

Comment: For instance the  for btcusdt on binance. Limit price is set about 0.5% higher than close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is a stop order. Replace stop= with limit= and it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

In strategy.entry the limit is about the order you are going to buy : what is the maximum price (if you want a long) you are ok to buy.

I think you are looking for a TP.

To set a TP, you can use (after your strategy.entry):

```
strategy.exit("TP", from_entry="Long", limit = 100000)
```